# reCAPTCHA PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, captcha, recaptcha

I am trying to add a reCAPTCHA to my PHP contact form with AJAX. I want the user to be displayed with the reCAPTCHA and have the user enter it. If it is incorrect it should display so without leaving the page. Only if the CAPTCHA is correct should it go to `contacts-go.php` and run the code to send the e-mail. I tried to do it from [this](http://www.darksideofthecarton.com/2008/12/15/validating-recaptcha-jquery-ajax/) example.

This is what I have on my **contact.php** page:

```
<?php   
    session_start();
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
            function validateCaptcha()
            {
                challengeField = $("input#recaptcha_challenge_field").val();
                responseField = $("input#recaptcha_response_field").val();
                //alert(challengeField);
                //alert(responseField);
                //return false;
                var html = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.recaptcha.php",
                data: "recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField + "&amp;recaptcha_response_field=" + responseField,
                async: false
                }).responseText;

                if(html == "success")
                {
                    $("#captchaStatus").html(" ");
                    // Uncomment the following line in your application
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#captchaStatus").html("Your captcha is incorrect. Please try again");
                    Recaptcha.reload();
                    return false;
                }
            }

        </SCRIPT>

        <script type="text/javascript">

</script>

    </head>


<body>
    <?php
        require_once("ajax.recaptcha.php");
    ?>

    <div id="login">
        <form method="post" onSubmit="return validateCaptcha()" action="contacts-go.php">

                <label>Message</label>
                <br />
                <textarea type="text" id="name" name="message" size="20"></textarea>

            <p><?php echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);?></p>

            <p style="color: red;" id="captchaStatus">&nbsp;</p>

            <input type=submit name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the **ajax.recaptcha.php** file

```
<?php

    //A. Load the Recaptcha Libary
    require_once("recaptchalib.php");
    require_once("recaptha-keys.php");  // my reCAPTCHA Keys

    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    if ($resp->is_valid) {
        ?>success<?
        $_SESSION['captcha'] = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
           "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
    }
?>
```

All I am getting is a blank page with the following:

`The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.(reCAPTCHA said: incorrect-captcha-sol)`

Comment: Removing the AJAX validateCaptcha function and changing to `action="ajax.recaptcha.php` , I notice that it seems to get get a "success". Aperently I have something wrong in my AJAX function that keeps getting false on `$resp->is_valid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I saw the contents of recaptchalib.php

  Noticed that, the api url and verify url doesnot work.

  ```
  define("RECAPTCHA_API_SERVER", "http://api.recaptcha.net");
  define("RECAPTCHA_API_SECURE_SERVER", "https://api-secure.recaptcha.net");
  define("RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER", "api-verify.recaptcha.net");
  ```
- Use this tutorial: http://www.jquery4u.com/forms/setup-user-friendly-captcha-jqueryphp/

  It uses google recaptcha.
- More links:

  http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore

  https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php

Comment: I changed over to the jquery4u sample. I edied it a bit, but after the Capthcha sucess or fails it just refreshes the whole page.

Comment: Either way, I just noticed that the only thing wrong with my original code always defaulting to false was that the **data** js value was set wrong. I changed it to `data: "form=signup&recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField + "&recaptcha_response_field=" + responseField,` . Now if the Captcha is incorrect it just displays the message that the captcha is wrong and refreshes the Captcha without refreshing the whole page

Comment: I also had to remove the else in the ajax.recaptcha.php file or else it would always display.

Comment: The last 2 links are broken.